# Invalid Parameter in AWS SNS Android App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, subscription, amazon-sns

I have integrated AWS SNS API in my Android app. When I open the app on my device, I get this error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.intap.appme, PID: 20780
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intap.appme/com.intap.appme.MainActivity}: com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Endpoint (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: e8589d7c-dec8-55e1-807f-cd16c8794be8)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                              Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Endpoint (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: e8589d7c-dec8-55e1-807f-cd16c8794be8)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2262)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.subscribe(AmazonSNSClient.java:1256)
                                                                 at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager.subscribeToTopic(PushManager.java:251)
                                                                 at com.intap.appme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The code lines in the log are those lines:
PushManager.java:251 (The whole method)

```
public void subscribeToTopic(final SnsTopic topic) {
    final SubscribeRequest request = new SubscribeRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpointArn);
    request.setTopicArn(topic.getTopicArn());
    request.setProtocol(SNS_PROTOCOL_APPLICATION);
    /* Line 251 -> */ final SubscribeResult result = sns.subscribe(request);

    // update topic and save subscription in shared preferences
    final String subscriptionArn = result.getSubscriptionArn();
    topic.setSubscriptionArn(subscriptionArn);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(topic.getTopicArn(), subscriptionArn).apply();
}
```

MainActivity.java:50

```
pushManager.subscribeToTopic(pushManager.getDefaultTopic());
```

I didn't really realized what is the invalid parameter in my app, so you could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, the invalid parameter is the **Endpoint**.
To get the endpoint you could do...

```
final CreatePlatformEndpointRequest request = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
    request.setPlatformApplicationArn(platformApplicationArn);
    request.setToken(gcmToken);
    final CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = snsClient.createPlatformEndpoint(request);
```

The endpoint can be retrieved by:

```
    result.getEndpointArn();
```

Comment: I don't have any variables goes by the names `gcmToken` or `snsClient` in my app. Could you please help me with that? Or is there another way to retrieve the Endpoint ARN?

Comment: Sorry, snsClient == sns
and gcmToken can be retrieved by:
gcmToken = instanceID.getToken(gcmSenderID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE); ... where instanceID is the InstanceID object (com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID)

Comment: OK, I've added it in my code but now I'm getting this error log: `Value null at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null`. Do you maybe know why am I getting this error and how to fix it? I'll post the full log in a few minutes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uvsmyGdk Here it is. Sorry it took me over 12 hours to post it.

Comment: Hi @ListMShon, could you please help me figure it out?